# how to select two different date in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I'm new to database and MySQL. I'm developing a stock tracking software backend with MySQL database. I have a problem in the MYSQL query.

I need to track price change for a certain period. how can I select two different column and row based on date. for example I need MYSQL to return 'open' value from date '2019-02-27' and 'close' value from date '2019-03-01';
and calculate the % differences in between two value(which is Decimal).

Is it possible to do this kind of query in MYSQL or I should write program which send two query. one to get 'open' from '2019-02-27' and other to get 'close' from '2019-03-01'.

here is the SQL fiddle for my problem http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb23e3/6

here is any example table

```
symbol |    date    |  open | close | low   | high 
----------------------------------------------------
   HCL | 2019-02-27 | 36.00 | 38.00 | 34.00 | 40.00
   HCL | 2019-02-28 | 37.00 | 39.00 | 36.00 | 41.00
   HCL | 2019-03-01 | 38.00 | 42.00 | 37.00 | 46.00
```

how can I get 'open' from date '2019-02-27' AND 'close' from date '2019-03-01'
and then calculated the % difference like (2019-02-27) 'open' value is 36.00 and (2019-03-01) 'close' value is 42.00 so the % percentage difference is +16.6%.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you can show the database structure and some sql query attempts.

Comment: really sorry! here is the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb23e3/6    I'm new to MySQL and database.

Comment: If you have a problem with a query, you better post your query and data structure instead of some html.

Comment: *and calculate the % differences in between two value* the values are 36 and 42, so what is *the % differences*?

Comment: for example, if a stock rises from 36 to 42. the differences is +16.6%. like that. I'm new to mysql. I don't know how to write query for this.

Answer (score 0):

With this you get the 3 needed columns:

```
select t.*, 
  concat(
    case when t.close > t.open then '+' else '' end,
    truncate(100.0 * (t.close - t.open) / t.open, 1)
  ) percentdif
from (
  select 
    (select open from dailyprice where date = '2019-02-27') open, 
    (select close from dailyprice where date = '2019-03-01') close
) t
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/knLHXp9PhY9yZuDzMnoCde/3)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to run two different queries and then calculate the difference of the returned values